# Hotkey for switching between windows

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, application-switcher

I've the three open windows:

[image]

I would like to switch between them as Alt+1 - first windows, Alt+2 - second window, Alt+3 - third windows and so on.

Is there any third-party tool or other ways to do it?

Comment: Why not use Alt+Tab?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if lubuntu keymapings are the same with ubuntu but the way to do it is hold down the Super/Windows Menu key and the keyboard shortcuts list will pop out. In ubuntu you can do it with Super+ 1-9.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with small script  [WindowsSwitcher](https://bitbucket.org/gekannt/windowsswitcher/overview)

Now to navigate to the necessary windows it's enough to click Windows+1, Windows+2 and so on.

Ctrl+Tab is not convenient when you have more than two windows and switch pretty often between them during the coding.

Unfortuantely I didn't find in GUI of Lubuntu how to set it.

Comment: Better not post a link- only answer of a script (which I didn't find by the way)

Comment: Do you mean I should provide more description of script?

Answer (score -1):

If you mean change tabs , as far as i know in firefox is :

Forward-

```
CTRL+TAB
```

Backward-

```
CTRL+SHIFT+TAB
```

More here:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly